# How to include Stripe button in Angular 2 template

Tags: angular

I am trying to include the Stripe button in my Angular 2 app, and upon adding the following code to my template, the script tags get removed by Angular. I understand that in Angular 2 script tags are removed from template text. What I would like to know is a step by step instruction for getting the code below to correctly run the script inside the form. Thank you in advance.

```
@Component({
 selector: 'payment',
 template: `
 <h1>Payment</h1>
 <form action="webtask-url" method="POST">
     <script
       src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
       class="stripe-button"
       data-key="pk_test_abcdabcdabcdabcdabcd"
       data-image="/assets/images/tj.png"
       data-name="My coffee"
       data-description="A cup of coffee for me"
       data-amount="214"
       data-locale="auto"
       data-panel-label="Buy me coffee"
       data-label="Buy $2.14 coffee for me">
     </script>
 </form>
`})
```

Comment: I would imagine you'll have to do it via JS using Stripe's custom integration steps: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom you don't want to be putting that type of JS script within Angular templates when it can be done in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

If you put it in index.html its not sanitized.
First we need to add stripe inside the head of our index.html file. This cannot be added to component templates because angular 2 will remove it.

https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js”>

Then make a checkout component

Answer (score 0):

You could add the Stripe script to your component via  ngOnInit event

Make sure your component class implements OnInit.

Implement something similar but for a SCRIPT tag, this is for DIV element:

```
              function addMyDivTag () { 
            // create a new div element 
            // and give it some content 
            var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
            var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and   greetings!"); 
            newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div. 

            // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
            var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
            document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
            }
```

Also looks like in RC1, HTML sanitazation is by default so, make sure you do disable it:

```
    class MyComponent {
      constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {
        // ONLY DO THIS FOR VALUES YOU KNOW TO BE SAFE! NEVER ALLOW USER DATA IN THIS!
        this.safeStyleValue = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('rotate(90deg)');
        // then bind to `safeStyleValue` in your template.
      }
    }
```

Comment: So one would replace rotate'(90deg)' with simply 'script' , is that correct?

Also excuse my ignorance as I am only beginning to learn Angular 2, but where would you have that function you defined above?